# how to convert Jquery and Ajax based script into pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to convert the following jquery and ajax based script into pure javascript

```
var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(json) {

                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried this but I think I am doing everything wrong

I followed https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery and http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ for my references

any one can help me in solving this

```
 var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add', true);

        request.onload = function() {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {

                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }

                fetch('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li').then(data => data.text()).then(data => {
                    document.querySelector('#cart > ul').innerHTML = data
                }).then(completeCallback)



                var json = this.response;
            }
        };

        request.onerror = function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        };

        request.send('product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to read your code because it doesn't seem to be indented in any sensible way

Comment: @TKoL do you mean format

Comment: Looks much better now. Is there a reason why you want to use `fetch` for some cases but `new XMLHttpRequest()` for others?

Comment: @TKoL there is no reason behind, but only is that I followed those documents which I mentioned in the question, I newbie in this

Comment: [this document](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery) only brings up `XMLHttpRequest ` as something for fetch to replace. I recommend you choose one -- probably fetch, as that works with promises, and that's what you really wanna be using. [be ware of how fetch handles http errors though](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/), as that can be a stumbling block